# How to run python 3 in google cloud?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to run a Python program in Google Cloud.

However, I found that [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/setting-up-eclipse) only supports Python 2.

What can I do?

Are there any other apps that supports Python 3?

Comment: I'm running Python 3 on app engine without issue. [Here's the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several products allow you to deploy Python 3 code:

- App Engine also supports Python 3: [Google App Engine Python 3 Standard Environment documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/).
- Cloud Functions has a Python 3 runtime: [The Python Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime).
- And you can define any runtime you want with [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run).